# set conditional visibility of templated field textbox in ASP.NET markup

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want the textbox in the templated field to be visible only if it contains text.
The textbox text is bound to my datasource but I can't access the textbox itself 
from within the server tags because it is in a templated field. I tried to do the 
following but I get index out of range when indexing the gridview(which makes sense).
Is there any other way to do this? or do i need to loop though the gridview
textboxes in the code behind? Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'  
           visible= '<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(Container.DisplayIndex).FindControl("Textbox1"), TextBox).Text) %>'>
       </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemple>
</TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Ternary Operator

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>
     Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Quantity").ToString()) ? false : true %> />
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a ternary operator in vb.net but just putting  Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Quantity").ToString()) %> /> works.  Thanks